# Looping through JSON object properties

Tags: php, json

I'm totally newbie what comes to programming so i'm not even quite sure if my terms are right but i would like to get some hints and tips what is best practice to loop through JSON object? Let's say i want all game names from following JSON print_r output.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_total] => 555
    [_links] => stdClass Object
        (
            [self] => https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top?limit=2&offset=0
            [next] => https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top?limit=2&offset=2
        )

    [top] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [viewers] => 86386
                    [channels] => 1159
                    [game] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => League of Legends
                            [_id] => 21779
                            [giantbomb_id] => 24024
                            [box] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [template] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-{width}x{height}.jpg
                                    [small] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-52x72.jpg
                                    [medium] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-136x190.jpg
                                    [large] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-272x380.jpg
                                )

                            [logo] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [template] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/League%20of%20Legends-{width}x{height}.jpg
                                    [small] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/League%20of%20Legends-60x36.jpg
                                    [medium] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/League%20of%20Legends-120x72.jpg
                                    [large] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/League%20of%20Legends-240x144.jpg
                                )

                            [_links] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [viewers] => 17288
                    [channels] => 162
                    [game] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft
                            [_id] => 138585
                            [giantbomb_id] => 42033
                            [box] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [template] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-{width}x{height}.jpg
                                    [small] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-52x72.jpg
                                    [medium] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-136x190.jpg
                                    [large] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-272x380.jpg
                                )

                            [logo] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [template] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-{width}x{height}.jpg
                                    [small] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-60x36.jpg
                                    [medium] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-120x72.jpg
                                    [large] => http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Hearthstone%3A%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft-240x144.jpg
                                )

                            [_links] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I can access single line (not sure if this is best practise either):

```
$OBJ->method()->top[0]->game->name;
```

But i'm more than clueless how to loop through all game names.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: use json_decode() to turn the data into an array, then use for or foreach to loop through and get what you need. You should be able to take those terms on an internet search and get yourself to your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty array, loop the objects top array and fill your empty array:

```
$allgames=array();
foreach($OBJ->method()->top as $ob){

    $allgames[] = $ob->game->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "name"s are accessed using `$OBJ->top[0]->game->name` etc...  So just `foreach` over the "top" array:

```
foreach($OBJ->top as $object) {
    echo $object->game->name;
}
```

Comment: I was pretty sure i tried this already. This gives following error: Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::

Comment: @SamSam: Not given the `$OBJ` you posted and the code I posted.

Comment: Sorry my bad i didn't notice the ->top. Now only problem is empty page. Doesn't echo anything. No errors which is progress i guess! Thank you.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 1):

When you load your JSON string into PHP you can use:

```
json_decode($string_of_json, true);
```

The `true` flag will load it into an array you can loop through using, for example, `foreach`.